# Swift / SpriteKit help: Increase CGFloat continuously to allow continuous rotation around a fixed point

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Im making a simple game with apple's SpriteKit and Swift and have encountered a problem. Im trying to get a paddle node (paddle) to rotate continuously around a fixed node (anchorNode) inside a circle; however, I cannot figure out how to make the paddle node (paddle) keep rotating around the fixed point node (anchorNode) because of the constrains in the SKAction.rotateByAngle statement making it end after a certain amount of time / rotation.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my code for reference:

```
    //Setting up anchor Node

    anchorNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    anchorNode.size.height = (self.frame.size.height / 1000)
    anchorNode.size.width = anchorNode.size.height
    self.addChild(anchorNode)


    //Setting up achor Node's physucs

    anchorNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: (circle.frame.size.height / 1000))
    anchorNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    anchorNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    anchorNode.physicsBody?.friction = 0


    //Making the anchor Node rotate

    let rotate = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(3.14), duration: NSTimeInterval(1.5))
    anchorNode.runAction(rotate)



    //Setting up the paddle node

    paddle.position = CGPointMake((circle.frame.width / 2), 0)
    paddle.size.height = (self.frame.size.height / 50)
    paddle.size.width = (self.frame.size.width / 7)

    anchorNode.addChild(paddle)
```

Comment: `anchorNode.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotate))`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code.

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
//How to make it spin
let speed = CGFloat(5)
let degreeRotation = CDouble(speed) * M_PI / 180
paddle.zRotation -= CGFloat(degreeRotation)
}
```

Comment: What does this code do exactly though, and would it replace the SKAction I already have in place?

Comment: It makes it rotate forever, unless you stop it and yes it would replace that SKAction

Comment: Which function is the code above located in? Is it in `didMoveToView`?

Comment: It errors because I cant use the 'override' part of the function apparently. Hmm

Comment: SKScene is the superclass for the GameScene subclass

Comment: That's weird because in one of my apps that code works.

Comment: I should be.. do you know of another way I could go about doing this? Im so lost as how to keep making the damn thing rotate continuously lmao

Comment: So, the error is with the override keyword of the update function, or the code inside it?

Comment: But sometimes Swift gives me errors, but when I run it, it sometimes it works even though it said there was an error, so try running it and see if it is actually an error

Comment: I keep getting an error, It might be a bug. My work-around to this problem was to just set the rotation for CGFloat to a huge number and set the NSTime interval proportionally so it will run for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Using this fixed my problem:

anchorNode.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotate))

Thanks, User:

0x141E